# Path analysis vs linear model

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, linear-model, path-model

I am not very familiar with path analysis, but was wondering why you would select this analysis to assess the relationships among variables rather than just fitting a generalized linear (or non-linear) model with a selection criteria?

Comment: GLMs do not estimate indirect effects.

Comment: @Alexis but using the product of coefficients method, one can simply multiply two coefficients together from two GLMs and get an estimate for an indirect effect, right?

Comment: @MarkWhite Begging the question of what one means by "path analysis" which, I believe, you just described.